# Equivalent for sarcastic question “X much?”

Tags: expressions, traduction, langage-informel

Is there any French equivalent for when people say something like “X much?”

It works like this:

Someone keeps stumbling clumsily or walking into things so you might say *“Wow, walk much?”*

It doesn’t mean “Do you walk a lot?” but rather *”You can’t walk at all”* or *”Can you even walk?”*

Another example:

Someone could be eating a salad and they start to choke on it a little so someone might say *“Swallow much?”* which is really just saying *“You definitely can’t swallow that”* or *”Don’t forget to swallow!”*

It’s a very sarcastic remark that’s pretty common so I was wondering if there was any French phrases that could be used as an equivalent?

Comment: I'm noticing you're asking a lot of question about colloquial stuff and some don't quite fit the guidelines of SE, feel free to hit my mail to ask for anything you can't ask here :) I'd be happy to answer your questions!

Comment: wow, really? thank you so much, that would be wonderful!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there are a perfect translation.

You can use "Apprends à X". But it can be a little mean, so use it carefully.

You can use it with good friend when they fail to do something simple.

Exemples :

"Apprends à macher"

"Apprends à manger"

"Apprends à marcher"

Comment: Oh you're right, I've forgotten that.. but I think it's more childish even really nasty ^^" "use it carrefully" is definitly a good advice !

Answer (score 2):

It's quite interesting but I'm pretty sure we don't have such a "generic" expression or phrase to say so.

For you example with salad, we may say (with sarcasm) something like:

> Eh t'étouffes pas hein !

For the fisrt one, you may hear:

> Regarde où tu mets les pieds quand tu marches !

So as you can see, there is no ordinary expression like the use of "much" as you explained. You might use common expressions we usualy use depending on the context.

Answer (score 2):

The expression that most closely resembles in meaning and form, in my opinion, would be "ça t'arrive de X?". For example:

> Ouah, **ça t'arrive de** marcher ?
>
> Dis, **ça t'arrive de** mâcher ?

It will be used with the same sarcastic undertone as "X much" in English and means the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Davantage inspiré du sens que de la morphologie :

> *Sais-tu c'est quoi/ce que c'est que/ce qu'est/qu'est-ce que c'est (que)...
>
>   Sais-tu (même)(comment)...
>
>   Es-tu (même) capable de/d'...*
>
> ...marcher/avaler/manger etc.

Comment: Je pense que cette réponse nécessite quelques clarifications, quitte à faire plusieurs phrases.

Comment: « Sais-tu c'est quoi », vraiment ?

Comment: C'est l'association de « sais-tu » et « c'est quoi » qui m'écorche un peu les oreilles. Mais je dois dire que je ne suis pas très au courant de ce type de langage. C'est peut-être vieilli mais j'utilise « Sais-tu ce que c'est que ... »

Comment: @Toto Ah, d'accord. C'est certainement pas un truc formel. Je trouve 10k+ hits sur le moteur de recherche, par exemple sais-tu c'est quoi le problème, le pire, une promesse ? etc. Probablement régional alors. Plusieurs des questions de ce contributeur traitent de formulations ou d'expressions assez informelles ou populaires à l'oral en anglais. Je puise spontanément davantage dans ma tradition orale, plutôt que dans celle plus régulière de l'écrit, d'où ces tournures et le lexique.